# javascript: Alter the output of a function to the specified decimal place

Tags: javascript, function, object, number-formatting

I am not very good with my javascript but recently needed to work with a library to output an aggregated table. Was using [fin-hypergrid](https://github.com/openfin/fin-hypergrid).

There was a part where I need to insert a sum function (rollups.sum(11) in this example)to an object so that it can compute an aggregated value in a table like so:

```
aggregates = {Value: rollups.sum(11)}
```

I would like to change this value to return 2 decimal places and tried:

```
rollups.sum(11).toFixed(2)
```

However, it gives the error : "rollups.sum(...).toFixed is not a function"

If I try something like:

```
parseFloat(rollups.sum(11)).toFixed(2)
```

it throws the error: "can't assign to properties of (new String("NaN")): not an object"

so it has to be a function object.

May I know if there is a way to alter the function rollups.sum(11) to return a function object with 2 decimal places?

(side info: rollups.sum(11) comes from a module which gives:

```
sum: function(columnIndex) {
    return sum.bind(this, columnIndex);
}
```

)

Sorry I could not post sample output here due to data confidentiality issues.
However, here is the code from the example I follow. I basically need to change rollups.whatever to give decimal places. The "11" in sum(11) here refers to a "column index".

```
window.onload = function() {

var Hypergrid = fin.Hypergrid;
var drillDown = Hypergrid.drillDown;
var TreeView = Hypergrid.TreeView;
var GroupView = Hypergrid.GroupView;
var AggView = Hypergrid.AggregationsView;

// List of properties to show as checkboxes in this demo's "dashboard"
var toggleProps = [{
        label: 'Grouping',
        ctrls: [
            { name: 'treeview', checked: false, setter: toggleTreeview },
            { name: 'aggregates', checked: false, setter: toggleAggregates },
            { name: 'grouping', checked: false, setter: toggleGrouping}
        ]
    }
];

function derivedPeopleSchema(columns) {
    // create a hierarchical schema organized by alias
    var factory = new Hypergrid.ColumnSchemaFactory(columns);
    factory.organize(/^(one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight)/i, { key: 'alias' });
    var columnSchema = factory.lookup('last_name');
    if (columnSchema) {
        columnSchema.defaultOp = 'IN';
    }
    //factory.lookup('birthState').opMenu = ['>', '<'];
    return factory.schema;
}

var customSchema = [
    { name: 'last_name', type: 'number', opMenu: ['=', '<', '>'], opMustBeInMenu: true },
    { name: 'total_number_of_pets_owned', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'height', type: 'number' },
    'birthDate',
    'birthState',
    'employed',
    { name: 'income', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'travel', type: 'number' }
];

var peopleSchema = customSchema;  // or try setting to derivedPeopleSchema

var gridOptions = {
        data: people1,
        schema: peopleSchema,
        margin: { bottom: '17px' }
    },
    grid = window.g = new Hypergrid('div#json-example', gridOptions),
    behavior = window.b = grid.behavior,
    dataModel = window.m = behavior.dataModel,
    idx = behavior.columnEnum;

console.log('Fields:');  console.dir(behavior.dataModel.getFields());
console.log('Headers:'); console.dir(behavior.dataModel.getHeaders());
console.log('Indexes:'); console.dir(idx);

var treeView, dataset;

function setData(data, options) {
    options = options || {};
    if (data === people1 || data === people2) {
        options.schema = peopleSchema;
    }
    dataset = data;
    behavior.setData(data, options);
    idx = behavior.columnEnum;
}

// Preset a default dialog options object. Used by call to toggleDialog('ColumnPicker') from features/ColumnPicker.js and by toggleDialog() defined herein.
grid.setDialogOptions({
    //container: document.getElementById('dialog-container'),
    settings: false
});

// add a column filter subexpression containing a single condition purely for demo purposes
if (false) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
    grid.getGlobalFilter().columnFilters.add({
        children: [{
            column: 'total_number_of_pets_owned',
            operator: '=',
            operand: '3'
        }],
        type: 'columnFilter'
    });
}

window.vent = false;

//functions for showing the grouping/rollup capabilities
var rollups = window.fin.Hypergrid.analytics.util.aggregations,
    aggregates = {
        totalPets: rollups.sum(2),
        averagePets: rollups.avg(2),
        maxPets: rollups.max(2),
        minPets: rollups.min(2),
        firstPet: rollups.first(2),
        lastPet: rollups.last(2),
        stdDevPets: rollups.stddev(2)
    },
    groups = [idx.BIRTH_STATE, idx.LAST_NAME, idx.FIRST_NAME];

var aggView, aggViewOn = false, doAggregates = false;
function toggleAggregates() {
    if (!aggView){
        aggView = new AggView(grid, {});
        aggView.setPipeline({ includeSorter: true, includeFilter: true });
    }
    if (this.checked) {
        grid.setAggregateGroups(aggregates, groups);
        aggViewOn = true;
    } else {
        grid.setAggregateGroups([], []);
        aggViewOn = false;
    }
}

function toggleTreeview() {
    if (this.checked) {
        treeView = new TreeView(grid, { treeColumn: 'State' });
        treeView.setPipeline({ includeSorter: true, includeFilter: true });
        treeView.setRelation(true, true);
    } else {
        treeView.setRelation(false);
        treeView = undefined;
        delete dataModel.pipeline; // restore original (shared) pipeline
        behavior.setData(); // reset with original pipeline
    }
}

var groupView, groupViewOn = false;
function toggleGrouping(){
    if (!groupView){
        groupView = new GroupView(grid, {});
        groupView.setPipeline({ includeSorter: true, includeFilter: true });
    }
    if (this.checked){
        grid.setGroups(groups);
        groupViewOn = true;
    } else {
        grid.setGroups([]);
        groupViewOn = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please provide sample output of your sum function ? I already tested with return output of digit and string in both case `parseFloat(rollups.sum(11)).toFixed(2)` is working fine

Comment: can you show what return value of sum(11) is, so I can see what kind of data structure you are dealing with.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot post a sample output as the data is confidential. However, there is an example which I follow religiously here [link](https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/). Basically if you click the "aggregate" check box, it will sum the values. I would just like to try changing the sum format to output 2 decimals. The script of the example can be found here [link](https://openfin.github.io/fin-hypergrid/js/demo.js).

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
(rollups.sum(11)).toFixed(2)
```

enclosing number in parentheses seems to make browser bypass the limit that identifier cannot start immediately after numeric literal

edited #2:

```
//all formatting and rendering per cell can be overridden in here
dataModel.getCell = function(config, rendererName) {
    if(aggViewOn)
    {
        if(config.columnName == "total_pets")
        {
            if(typeof(config.value) == 'number')
            {
                config.value = config.value.toFixed(2);
            }
            else if(config.value && config.value.length == 3 && typeof(config.value[1]) == 'number')
            {
                config.value = config.value[1].toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    } 
    return grid.cellRenderers.get(rendererName);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Bod! I tried that, but it returns an error: TypeError: rollups.sum(...).toFixed is not a function. I think any modification should end up with returning a function object instead.

Comment: how about overriding cell rendering, @NoobPoke? have a look at my edited answer please

Comment: hi Bod, I placed this code right after the definitions for the aggregate toggles. Then all the cells turned yellow and had the text "renderer is undefined"

Comment: @NoobPoke, I forgot the rest of the function, the second modification could be the one, I hope :)